# Loading multiple shared libraries with different versions

Tags: linux, gcc, versioning, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have an executable on Linux that loads `libfoo.so.1` (that's a `SONAME`) as one of its dependencies (via another shared library). It also links to another system library, which, in turn, links to a **system** version, `libfoo.so.2`. As a result, **both** `libfoo.so.1` and `libfoo.so.2` are loaded during execution, and code that was supposed to call functions from library with version 1 ends up calling (binary-incompatible) functions from a newer system library with version 2, because some symbols stay the same. The result is usually stack smashing and a subsequent segfault.

Now, the library which links against the older version is a closed-source third-party library, and I can't control what version of `libfoo` it compiles against. Assuming that, the only other option left is rebuilding a bunch of system libraries that currently link with `libfoo.so.2` to link with `libfoo.so.1`.

Is there any way to avoid replacing system libraries wiith local copies that link to older `libfoo`? Can I load both libraries and have the code calling correct version of symbols? So I need some special symbol-level versioning?

Comment: Alex: how did you solve the problem? could you please share it with us?

Comment: @Nawaz I don't remember exactly, it has been 9 years ago! I _think_ I gave up and made it so that only one version of the library is loaded.

Comment: Alex, [this article](https://blog.habets.se/2012/05/Shared-libraries-diamond-problem.html) talks about this problem and have also suggested a solution. I've not tried it yet. But it's interesting to know/explore.

Answer (score 8):

You may be able to do some version script tricks:

http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/binutils-2.9.1/html_node/ld_26.html

This may require that you write a wrapper around your lib that pulls in libfoo.so.1 that exports some symbols explicitly and masks all others as local.  For example:

MYSYMS {
     global:
         foo1;
                 foo2;
     local:
                 *;
};

and use this when you link that wrapper like:

gcc -shared -Wl,--version-script,mysyms.map -o mylib  wrapper.o -lfoo -L/path/to/foo.so.1

This should make libfoo.so.1's symbols local to the wrapper and not available to the main exe.

Answer (score 0):

I can only come up with a work-around. Which would be to statically link a version of the "system library" that you are using. For your static build, you could make it link against the same old version as the third-party library. Given that it does not rely on the newer version...

Perhaps it is also possible to avoid these problems with not linking to the third-party library the ordinary way. Instead, your program could load it at execution time. Perhaps then it could be shadowed against the rest. But I don't know much about that.