# Program use two conflicting shared libraries

Tags: c, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have a shared library `A.so`. There is a function `foo()` defined in it. This `foo()` function depends on a shared library `libnl-1.so`. The relationship is below:

```
A.so 
    {
      foo() => libnl-1
    }
```

I have a program `app`. It calls two functions, `foo()` and `bar()`. `bar()` needs another version of libnl, libnl-3. The relationship is below:

```
app {
      foo()
      bar() => libnl-3
    }
```

I compiled app using `cc -o app -lnl-3 -lA`. But I found my app always crashes. It seems that `foo()` is calling into libnl-3 instead of libnl-1 (I have no idea how to verify this). Can anyone help me out? If I want to do this, what should I do? Change the linking order?

Comment: You may use `$ LD_DEBUG=all ./app` to check from where the dynamic linker imports symbols to your program.

Comment: Why do you think it is a good idea to link two versions of one library at the same time?  You really need to rethink what you're doing so that you only use one version of the library, preferably the latest.

Comment: Why is the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228117/loading-multiple-shared-libraries-with-different-versions?rq=1 of no use for your case? (I just assume here that you cannot just C&P the two functions you need out of the libs because of them being closed source or  whatever)

Answer (score 1):

> If I want to do this, what should I do?

On UNIX (unlike a windows DLL), a shared library is *not* a self-contained unit, and does not function in isolation. The design of UNIX shared libraries is to emulate archive libraries as much as possible. One of the consequences is that (by default) the first defined function "wins". In your case, `libnl-3` and `libnl-1` likely define the same functions, and you'll get the definition from whichever library is *first* (which will be wrong for one call, or the other).

> Change the linking order?

That will change the first library, and will *still* be wrong.

So, what *should* you do?

The best option is *not* to link incompatible versions of the same library. Pick one of `libnl-1` or `libnl-3` and *stick with it*.

If you can't, you *may* be able to achieve desired result by linking `A.so` with `-Bsymbolic`, or by making `bar` use `dlopen("libnl-3.so", RTLD_LOCAL|RTLD_LAZY)` to lookup needed `libnl-3` function instead of using it directly.