# Two library of different versions in an application

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Consider a scenario where there are two shared library of different version.Consider A.1.so linked to B.so and A.2.so linked to C.so. Now both B.so and C.so are linked to d.exe . When B.so wants to invoke function in A.1.so, it ends up calling function in A.2.so .Because of this , it gives us undefined behaviour.

Now I want my B.so invoke only A.1.so.I can only modify A.1.so and B.so , nothing else. Using `dlopen()` is one of the option, but for using `dlopen()`, I have to make heavy changes in B.so. There are many solutions given earlier in Stack Overflow, but nothing seems to work. Kindly note that I can make code changes in A.1.so and B.so only.

Is there any other solution to this problem other than `dlopen()`. I have mentioned some of the links below.

- https://blog.habets.se/2012/05/Shared-libraries-diamond-problem.html
- https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/network/ssl/qsslsocket_openssl_symbols_p.h.html
- https://www.mailerq.com/blog/good-reasons-to-use-dlopen
- [Loading multiple shared libraries with different versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228117/loading-multiple-shared-libraries-with-different-versions?rq=1)
- [Program use two conflicting shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330182/program-use-two-conflicting-shared-libraries)
- [C++ two libraries depend on same lib but different versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351215/c-two-libraries-depend-on-same-lib-but-different-versions)
- [Linking with multiple versions of a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232822/linking-with-multiple-versions-of-a-library/3249833#3249833)
- [C++ two libraries depend on same lib but different versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351215/c-two-libraries-depend-on-same-lib-but-different-versions)

Comment: Can you rename A.1.so to MyA.1.so ? And link B.so to that ?

Comment: (you'll obviously have the rename the symbols exposed by the library to match)

Comment: @SanderDeDycker i tried , it did not work , even if the library name is different, the function name inside the library is same

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I tried--default-symver, it did not work, maybe i have made some mistake , but it did not work.

Comment: just prepend `my_` to all external symbols (in the code)

Comment: @SanderDeDycker If I add my_ in front of all symbols , I have to make changes in A.1.so and B.so , and that changes will be really huge.This change is no better than dlopen().I need something which can make this thing work with minimal changes.

Comment: Do you also want for C.so to invoke only from A.2.so ? Or are you ok with A1.so to hide A2.so implementation ?

Comment: @MichaelCMS actually i don't want A1.so to hide A2.so . Anyway for knowledge sake lets assume that i want A1.so to hide A2.so.One possiblle way is using LD_PRELOAD. Is there any other way??

Comment: @AbhishekGarg LD_PRELOAD is the correct way for hiding.For what you are asking I think that what you are seeking to do is to compile the B.so with static linkage to A1.so. You cannot achieve what you want while having both using dynamic linkage. However if you static link B.so to A1.so the calls should work.

Comment: @MichaelCMS i tried static linking , it did not work

Comment: @SanderDeDycker how to  prepend my_ to all external symbols

Comment: @AbhishekGarg : just type it ? Or find/replace ? Or ...

Comment: @SanderDeDycker When u say prepend my_ to all external symbols, did u mean renaming all functions in codebase

Comment: @AbhishekGarg : yes

Answer (score 0):

can you wrap all code in `A1.cpp` in `namespace A1` and add a `using namespace A1` to `B.cpp`?
By `A1.cpp` an `B.cpp` I mean all the relevant translation units for `A1.so` and `B.so`.